# Does Cordova Keychain Plugin works for iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, cordova, keychain

I'm working on a Cordova mobile app where I need to store a key that will be used to encrypt/decrypt data in Keychain. I need to target from iOS platforms 6.1 (iPhone 3GS). I found a [cordova plugin](https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin) that helps to store sensitive information in Keychain. I heard from my friend that Keychain feature is available only in later versions of iOS. Does this plugin works in iOS 6.1 version?

Comment: The [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html) has been available since iOS 2, whether or not the plugin works I can not tell.

Comment: Is the Keychain you say is different from iCloud keychain?

Comment: Yes and No, the Keychain is available on all iOS devices from iOS 2. The iCould support for the keychain was introduced in iOS 7. But there are no API changes. It just means that the keychain is synced between devices via iCloud.

Comment: Cool. If you post the comment as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html) is available on all iOS devices from iOS 2. The iCould support for the keychain was introduced in iOS 7. But there are no API changes. It just means that the keychain is synced between devices via iCloud.